# Sketching conic section in canonical form

Tags: graphing-functions, canonical-transformation

If I have found the canonical form to be $x^2/2^2-y^2/3^2-1=0$. Do I simply sketch this as I would a usual $(x,y)$ graph? As when I typed this into a graphing calculator I got 4 lines (2 straight and 2 curved). So I am not too sure if its right.

Also when working the original equation and getting it into canonical form I am asked to state the translation and orthogonal transformation? What do these exactly refer to.

$5x^2 + 12xy − 22x − 12y − 19 = 0$ was the original equation.

Comment: it depends on the graphing calculator you are using:  Geogebra will handle well both the original and canonical form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve for $y$ and get two solutions (one positive, one negative):

[image]

The "canonical" form of such an unrotated conic is:

$$\frac{(x-a)^2}{b^2} + \frac{(y-c)^2}{d^2} = 0,$$

placing the center at $(a,c)$ with axes of length $b$ and $d$.

Comment: Thanks for this for some reason I got the same but with two straight lines between the curves.

Comment: Straight lines would be linear relations... certainly not the case here.  These are the directrixes.  I can only imagine that your plotting software puts in these asymptotes automatically.  The straight lines would go through $(0,0)$, which clearly does not solve the equation.

Comment: Thanks, it was because of the asymptotes.

Comment: So maybe now you'll accept ($\checkmark$) or at minimum upvote (+1) my answer?

Comment: I tried but it says my reputation is too low to upvote :(

Comment: But the tick worked didn't know about that.